# Printing elements from a file using Scanner from Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hello Please i need some help in Java. Since i have been trying to output lines from a file using Scanner but i dont succeed. This is how the file content looks like :

```
4
5
3->1->25
1->0->12
2->0->-5
0->1->0
2->1->7
```

The first thing i tried to do was to output information starting from the third line and it worked perfectly well. This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String line = null;
    try{
        scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("graphe.txt")));
        //in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("graphe.txt"));
        scanner.useDelimiter("->");
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){

            int value = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.skip(scanner.delimiter());
            int value2 = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.skip(scanner.delimiter());
            String value3 = scanner.nextLine();
            int value3Int = Integer.parseInt(value3);
            System.out.println(value + " - > " + value2 + " cost " + value3Int);
        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (scanner != null){
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

But then when i inserted values 4 and  (first and second line) i tried to figure how to deal with it. The first thing i did was to try to use the if condition to see if the delimeter exist and if it doesn't i print it out :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String line = null;
    try{
        scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("graphe.txt")));
        //in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("graphe.txt"));
        scanner.useDelimiter("->");
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){

            String find = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!(find.contains("->"))){
                System.out.println(find);
            }
            else {
                int value = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.skip(scanner.delimiter());
                int value2 = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.skip(scanner.delimiter());
                String value3 = scanner.nextLine();
                int value3Int = Integer.parseInt(value3);
                System.out.println(value + " - > " + value2 + " cost " + value3Int);
            }
        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (scanner != null){
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

But it didn't work like expeceted and i had this error as output

```
4

5

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)

1 - > 0 cost 12

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)

0 - > 1 cost 0

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at com.tpTG.LectureGrapheMatrice.main(LectureGrapheMatrice.java:25)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please i know i can deal with it but i've been thinking over and over but i can't figure how to. Please help thanks.

Comment: Do you want to ignore the 4 and 5 or something else?

Comment: No i want to print all those lines

Comment: You don't know how many of these single number lines there are, right?

Comment: Sorry ? Please i'm not getting what you are trying to say. But what i'm saying is that i want to print out all the lines from the file

Comment: Once you've read a line with `scanner.nextLine()` and decided that it has a delimiter, you start calling `scanner.next()` and `scanner.skip()` to try and dissect it.  But at that point, `scanner.next()` and `scanner.skip()`  are now reading from the **next** line.

Comment: I mean will lines that doesn't match the `some number -> some number -> some number` pattern only appear at the start. Or do you want to handle all kinds of situations?

Comment: Instead of `.useDelimiter("->")`, try checking for and reading delimiters explicitly with `.hasNext("->")` and `.next("->")`

Comment: Exactly i want to handle all kinds of situations. That's why i first taught that including the **if** could handle it.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a regex `replaceAll` for each line might do it.

```
// no need to set delimiter
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("^((?:\\+|-)?\\d+)->((?:\\+|-)?\\d+)->((?:\\+|-)?\\d+)$", 
                                                "$1 -> $2 costs $3");
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

If the input matches the pattern, you format it to "x -> y costs z", otherwise `replaceAll` won't do anything and you output the same line.

If you want the three values, you can access the captured values with `Matcher.group`,

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("((?:\\+|-)?\\d+)->((?:\\+|-)?\\d+)->((?:\\+|-)?\\d+)").matcher(line);
    if (m.matches()) {
        // m.group(1), m.group(2) and m.group(3) are the three values as strings. You can convert them to ints yourself.
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + " -> " + m.group(2) + " costs " + m.group(3));
    } else {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked just fine. But if you don't mind i just wanted to know what the issue with my code ?

Comment: @The_Thinker It is just as Kevin Anderson had said. You call `nextInt` after `nextLine`. The int you scanned won't be the ints in the line you scanned, because the scanner has already scanned that line and moved on. You need to extract the int from `find`, not scan new ints.

Comment: Yeah but how to structure it i don't yet know. Beceaus later i will like to handle those values that is : x -> y costs z wher x gonna be the line y the column and z the value of (x,y)

Comment: I will try it out with you regex solution but with mine i'm still trying to figure it out as @Kevin Anderson said